styling dataframe with multi-index and export to excel
I have a dataframe like this:
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Counterparty': ['foo', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fizz','fizz'],
        'Commodity': ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar','bar'],
        'DealType': ['Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy'],
        'StartDate': ['07/01/2024', '09/01/2024', '10/01/2024', '11/01/2024', '12/01/2024'],
        'FloatPrice': [18.73, 17.12, 17.76, 18.72, 19.47],
        'MTMValue':[10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
        })


df = df.set_index(['Counterparty', 'Commodity', 'DealType','StartDate']).sort_index()[['FloatPrice', 'MTMValue']]

print(df)

i am trying to apply styles to the dataframe before I export it to excel. This is what I have done so far:
def style_index(s):
    return "background-color: lightblue; text-align: center; border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: middle;"

def style_header(s):
    return "background-color: lightgrey; text-align: center;"

styled_df = df.style.set_properties(**{
                            'background-color': 'darkblue',
                            'color': 'white',
                            'text-align': 'center'}).map_index(style_index).map_index(style_header, axis="columns")

which yields this:

however I need the dataframe to look like this:


the index column headers are not getting highlighted
the items in the index are not aligned in the center

Here is how I export my dataframes,
item is a dataframe:
with pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
            for item in list:
                styled_df = item.style.set_properties(**{
                            'background-color': '#0F243E',
                            'color': 'white',
                            'text-align': 'center'}).map_index(style_index).map_index(style_header, axis="columns")

                styled_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name, startrow=rowPos, float_format = "%0.2f", index=bool)

Also, I feel like there is a more efficient way to accomplish what I am already doing so any suggestions are appreciated.
EDIT: managed to get the text vertically aligned in the center, but still no luck with highlighting the index column headers

I'm not sure how to get the index name using map_index, however, you can set it with set_table_style:
styled_df = styled_df.set_table_styles([dict(selector='.index_name', props=[('text-align', 'center'), ('background-color', 'lightgray')])])


Unfortunately, this did not work for me. The index header is still not getting styled

@iBeMeltin set_table_styles is not set values 'inplace' you have to assign it to the DataFrame object. I've updated my answer.

I understand, but the style still is not being applied

After a LOT of sifting through documentation, this was the simplest solution I could find:
def style_index(s):
    return "background-color: lightblue; text-align: center; border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: middle;"


styled_df = df.style.set_properties(
    **{"background-color": "darkblue", "color": "white", "text-align": "center"}
).map_index(style_index)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
styled_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]

header_format = workbook.add_format()
header_format.set_bg_color("#d3d3d3")
header_format.set_align("center")
for i, name in enumerate(
    ["Counterparty", "Commodity", "DealType", "StartDate", "FloatPrice", "MTMValue"]
):
    worksheet.write(f"{string.ascii_uppercase[i]}1", name, header_format)

writer.close()


thank you for your time and effort, but I cannot use xlsxwriter. I will update my question to show how I export my dataframes

@iBeMeltin Why can't you use xlsxwriter?

I am exporting multiple dataframes to multiple different sheets throughout my script. xlsxwriter does not have append mode so it will overwrite all the sheets. Also, I find xlsxwriter to be very cumbersome and like to avoid it when possible.
